# PhpStorm - Disable generation of '.sass-cache' on compilation (file-watcher)

Tags: sass, phpstorm

So, the compilation of (`_`)`file.scss` files to `*.css` files works great. Just one thing: For each file the watcher encounters, it creates a cache file. It does this right next to the file being compiled, e.g.:

- _partial.scss
- style.scss

Generates:

- /.sass-cache/C0mpl1cat3dh4sh/_partial.scss
- /.sass-cache/C0mpl1cat3dh4sh/style.scss
- style.css

Of course I could simple delete the files when they're generated. Could add them to .gitignore. But these are work-arounds.

How to disable the generation of these cache files?

In the options I could not find an option to do this when searching "cache", "file watcher" or "watch".

Extra info:

- Running 2018.3.3, built 9th January 2019
- Have not seen this before, though haven't mucked around with scss in a while (2 - 3 months), so not sure if it's a recent addition to PhpStorm

[image: File watcher options]

Comment: Try node-sass instead of Ruby-powered one, it's faster and does not create any cache files. Other than that -- have you tried adding `--no-cache` at the start of Arguments field?

Comment: Hmmm very nice, the `--no-cache` works :-) Speed is honestly not a concern, so long as the output is bug-free and proper, though I will keep it in mind for a next clean system installation (few months till new pc :-) ). Guessing theres a man-page somewhere for this ruby sass? If you add it this as an answer (with link to docs perhaps) I'll mark it as answer. (Also, did not know what sass watcher thingy was installed, it asked "Do you want a SCSS file watcher?" "Yes" was my answer ;-) The rest is, as we say in Dutch: water under the bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch a terminal and find out the command-line switches offered by your SASS implementation, typically with:

```
sass --help
```

You appear to be using old Ruby SASS. If I recall correctly, the switch was:

```
--no-cache
```

Add it to the *Arguments* input box and you should be done.

As already mentioned, Ruby SASS is no longer being developed so it can be a good moment to switch to Dart SASS, which does not have any cache to care about.

Comment: Marking yours as answer. Can you add this link to it? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#caching Found that after [LazyOne's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261871/phpstorm-disable-generation-of-sass-cache-on-compilation-file-watcher/54266067#comment95347998_54261871), however he's not provided an answer to mark. If he ends up providing one I'll mark it as he provided the solution first, else it's yours as my specific issue was solved due to the `--no-cache` flag.

Comment: That link talks about caching but only from the perspective of Ruby developers. I've been looking for proper documentation about command-line switches but I couldn't find it. (Don't worry too much about which answer to accept, just pick the one you think will help others most.)

Answer (score -1):

Ruby sass is [deprecated](https://github.com/sass/ruby-sass#ruby-sass-is-deprecated) already for a while, development is moved towards [Dart](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) implementation while [LibSass](https://sass-lang.com/libsass) is also actual implementation, but may step behind Dart implementation in some aspects. LibSass have plenty of integrations for various languages, please refer documentation by link above.

Both of these implementations are much faster then Ruby sass and doesn't produce any additional cache directories.